# Could we use the present perfect in this sentence (with past simple tense)?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

Consider

> Somebody____________ all the juice; the bottle was empty.

I know it is okay  (you can correct me here) to write the sentence using the past perfect  *had drunk* or the past simple  *drank*, so you can get

> Somebody *had drunk* ( or *drank*) all the juice; the   bottle was empty.

But is it okay to write the sentence using the *present perfect*?

To say:

> Somebody *has drunk*  all the juice; the bottle was empty.

thank you

Comment: What is your question? Can you use *was* in that sentence even if you discovered the bottle was empty two minutes ago? (Definitely, yes.) Or can you combine the present perfect with *was* in that sentence, even if it happened two minutes ago? (I'm not sure; it's complicated.)

Comment: @PeterShor sorry for that , I have edited the question.

Comment: The *present perfect* is NOT  a "past tense." So I have edited your question title.

Comment: @AlanCarmack where is 2 minutes ago in this question? The OP want to know if he can use "has drunk" (the present perfect) with the bottle **was** empty (simple past)

Comment: @Ahmad "2 minutes ago" has been in the title since the beginning, and I would think it is important to the OP. However, since it remains unclear what exactly the OP is asking,  I think we should stop editing the question until the OP clarifies.

Comment: I have edited the title , sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of your action was in the past (and the bottle *was* empty), the action happened in the past. But if you want to use the present perfect, the result will be in the present simple, *is*, respectively.

> Somebody has drunk all the juice. The bottle is empty.